# Ошибка в аргументе функции(javascript)

Tags: javascript

- Всем хай, я бы хотел, чтобы аргумент **name** через
- свою функцию **other** передал значение **"Колян"** в **name**
- По задумке **alert** должен выводить **"АнтохаКолян"**
- Составил скрипт, но здесь ошибка((((

```js
function user(test, name = other()){
alert(test + name);

function other(){
name = 'Колян'; 

};   
};


user('Антоха ');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function user(test, name = other()) {
  alert(test + name);
}

function other() {
  return 'Колян';
}

user('Антоха ');
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо)